# How do I read from a File to an array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I am trying to read from a file to an array. I tried two different styles and both aren't working. Below are the two styles.

#### Style 1

```
public class FileRead {

        int i;
        String a[] = new String[2];
        public void read() throws FileNotFoundException {
            //Z means: "The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any"

            a[i] = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\nnanna\\Documents\\login.txt")).useDelimiter("\\n").next();
           for(i=0; i<=a.length; i++){
            System.out.println("" + a[i]);
           }


        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
            new FileRead().read();

        }
    }
```

#### Style 2

```
public class FileReadExample {
    private int j = 0;
    String path = null;

    public void fileRead(File file){
StringBuilder attachPhoneNumber = new StringBuilder();
        try{

        FileReader read = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(read);



        while((path = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            String a[] = new String[3];
            a[j] = path;
            j++;
          System.out.println(path);

            System.out.println(a[j]);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        }catch(IOException exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I need it to read each line of string and store each line in an array. But neither works. How do I go about it?

Comment: how do they not work?  (what are the errors or incorrectness in the output?)

Comment: Please post only the relevant parts of your code, **not** the commented-out stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Do yourself a favor and use a library that provides this functionality for you, e.g.

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/):

```
// one String per File
String data = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
// or one String per Line
List<String> data = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

[Commons / IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
// one String per File
String data = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
// or one String per Line
List<String> data = FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do (partly with quite a lot of code commented out, leaving other code which won't even compile), but I'd recommend you look at using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/):

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

That way you don't need to mess around with the file handling yourself at all.